# Would it be possible to construct a capacitor from clear tape and graphite?

Tags: capacitor

I read that graphene can be produced by attaching clear tape to graphite and then removing it.  This results in a layer of graphene on the tape.  If one were to take a very lone strip of clear tape, apply a layer of graphene, roll up the tape, and make suitable connections to wires, could a capacitor be produced?

Comment: Looks like paper capacitors. You can make one with two aluminium foils and two sheets of thin paper.

Comment: To make the "capacitor" that you ask about, if it was going to be feasible, you would need two if your coated long strips of clear tape that was coated.

Comment: Yes, but what's so special about using graphene in this way to make a foil capacitor? The capacity is related (beside other things) to thinkness of the insulator, not the thickness of the conductors.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't get large continuous sheets of graphene that way. You just get lots of tiny disconnected pieces. If the pieces are not in electrical contact with each other, they won't form a plate that can be used to build a capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Instead look into the various adhesives that contain graphite, come out clear, and are usually conductive.   Everlube has a number of dry film adhesives containing graphite which may be conductive.